# Exchange 2013 - migrating to gmail - all messages now drafts

Tags: exchange-2013, gmail

I have an exchange 2013 server that we are migrating data to G Suite (gmail).  During this process it decided to make all of the messages set as draft.  So it makes it so no one can reply to an email without editing it as a draft.  They are also listed as draft in Gmail now.
Is there possibly a shell command that can be ran against the database so I can convert all of the messages from draft to a regular message?

Comment: What did GSuite support say about this?

Comment: Waiting on a response from them.  Was just hoping someone else had run into something similar and already had an answer.

Comment: Well, what you did is very unorthodox, so I highly doubt you'll hear from anyone.